# strace with errors on openat syscall with Lustre FS, RHEL 8, overall intermittent latency

Tags: rhel, latency, lustre

Does anyone see what could be causing this intermittent latency? At various times all commands become slow on login, compute and head nodes and only with logins associated with Lustre, i.e., root and local logins do not have this latency. 45 errors on openat syscall does not sound normal.

```
strace -ttt -T -C -w touch newfilethat 
    1662064377.602061 execve("/usr/bin/touch", ["touch", "newfilethat"], 0x7fffffffd278 /* 75 vars */) = 0 <0.000203>
    1662064377.602361 brk(NULL)             = 0x55555576b000 <0.000007>
    1662064377.602385 arch_prctl(0x3001 /* ARCH_??? */, 0x7fffffffd1a0) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument) <0.000006>
    1662064377.602443 access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory) <0.000007>
    1662064377.602516 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/path/to/slurm/current/lib64/slurm/tls/haswell/avx512_1/x86_64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory) <0.000021>
    1662064377.602582 stat("/path/to/slurm/current/lib64/slurm/tls/haswell/avx512_1/x86_64", 0x7fffffffc3f0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory) <0.000009>
    1662064377.602610 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/path/to/slurm/current/lib64/slurm/tls/haswell/avx512_1/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory) <0.000008>
    1662064377.602634 stat("/path/to/slurm/current/lib64/slurm/tls/haswell/avx512_1", 0x7fffffffc3f0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory) <0.000008>
    1662064377.602657 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/path/to/slurm/current/lib64/slurm/tls/haswell/x86_64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory) <0.000008>
    1662064377.602680 stat("/path/to/slurm/current/lib64/slurm/tls/haswell/x86_64", 0x7fffffffc3f0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory) <0.000008>
    1662064377.602703 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/path/to/slurm/current/lib64/slurm/tls/haswell/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory) <0.000008>
    1662064377.602725 stat("/path/to/slurm/current/lib64/slurm/tls/haswell", 0x7fffffffc3f0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory) <0.000008>
    1662064377.602748 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/path/to/slurm/current/lib64/slurm/tls/avx512_1/x86_64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory) <0.000008>
    1662064377.602772 stat("/path/to/slurm/current/lib64/slurm/tls/avx512_1/x86_64", 0x7fffffffc3f0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory) <0.000008>
    1662064377.602794 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/path/to/slurm/current/lib64/slurm/tls/avx512_1/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory) <0.000008>
    1662064377.602817 stat("/path/to/slurm/current/lib64/slurm/tls/avx512_1", 0x7fffffffc3f0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory) <0.000008>
    1662064377.602840 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/path/to/slurm/current/lib64/slurm/tls/x86_64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory) <0.000008>
    1662064377.602862 stat("/path/to/slurm/current/lib64/slurm/tls/x86_64", 0x7fffffffc3f0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory) <0.000008>
    1662064377.602885 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/path/to/slurm/current/lib64/slurm/tls/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory) <0.000008>
    1662064377.602907 stat("/path/to/slurm/current/lib64/slurm/tls", 0x7fffffffc3f0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory) <0.000008>
    1662064377.602930 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/path/to/slurm/current/lib64/slurm/haswell/avx512_1/x86_64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory) <0.000009>
    1662064377.602955 stat("/path/to/slurm/current/lib64/slurm/haswell/avx512_1/x86_64", 0x7fffffffc3f0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory) <0.000008>
    1662064377.602979 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/path/to/slurm/current/lib64/slurm/haswell/avx512_1/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory) <0.000009>
    1662064377.603002 stat("/path/to/slurm/current/lib64/slurm/haswell/avx512_1", 0x7fffffffc3f0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory) <0.000008>
    1662064377.603025 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/path/to/slurm/current/lib64/slurm/haswell/x86_64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory) <0.000008>
    1662064377.603048 stat("/path/to/slurm/current/lib64/slurm/haswell/x86_64", 0x7fffffffc3f0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory) <0.000008>
    1662064377.603071 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/path/to/slurm/current/lib64/slurm/haswell/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory) <0.000008>
    1662064377.603094 stat("/path/to/slurm/current/lib64/slurm/haswell", 0x7fffffffc3f0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory) <0.000008>
    1662064377.603117 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/path/to/slurm/current/lib64/slurm/avx512_1/x86_64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory) <0.000009>
    1662064377.603140 stat("/path/to/slurm/current/lib64/slurm/avx512_1/x86_64", 0x7fffffffc3f0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory) <0.000008>
    1662064377.603164 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/path/to/slurm/current/lib64/slurm/avx512_1/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory) <0.000009>
    1662064377.603187 stat("/path/to/slurm/current/lib64/slurm/avx512_1", 0x7fffffffc3f0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory) <0.000008>
    1662064377.603211 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/path/to/slurm/current/lib64/slurm/x86_64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory) <0.000008>
    1662064377.603233 stat("/path/to/slurm/current/lib64/slurm/x86_64", 0x7fffffffc3f0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory) <0.000008>
    1662064377.603257 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/path/to/slurm/current/lib64/slurm/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory) <0.000008>
    1662064377.603280 stat("/path/to/slurm/current/lib64/slurm", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=12288, ...}) = 0 <0.000011>
    1662064377.603308 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/path/to/slurm/current/lib64/tls/haswell/avx512_1/x86_64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory) <0.000009>
    1662064377.603332 stat("/path/to/slurm/current/lib64/tls/haswell/avx512_1/x86_64", 0x7fffffffc3f0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory) <0.000009>
    1662064377.603356 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/path/to/slurm/current/lib64/tls/haswell/avx512_1/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory) <0.000009>
    1662064377.603379 stat("/path/to/slurm/current/lib64/tls/haswell/avx512_1", 0x7fffffffc3f0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory) <0.000008>
    1662064377.603402 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/path/to/slurm/current/lib64/tls/haswell/x86_64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory) <0.000008>
    1662064377.603424 stat("/path/to/slurm/current/lib64/tls/haswell/x86_64", 0x7fffffffc3f0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory) <0.000008>
    1662064377.603446 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/path/to/slurm/current/lib64/tls/haswell/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory) <0.000008>
    1662064377.603469 stat("/path/to/slurm/current/lib64/tls/haswell", 0x7fffffffc3f0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory) <0.000008>
    1662064377.603491 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/path/to/slurm/current/lib64/tls/avx512_1/x86_64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory) <0.000011>
    1662064377.603517 stat("/path/to/slurm/current/lib64/tls/avx512_1/x86_64", 0x7fffffffc3f0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory) <0.000008>
    1662064377.603540 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/path/to/slurm/current/lib64/tls/avx512_1/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory) <0.000014>
    1662064377.603569 stat("/path/to/slurm/current/lib64/tls/avx512_1", 0x7fffffffc3f0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory) <0.000008>
    1662064377.603592 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/path/to/slurm/current/lib64/tls/x86_64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory) <0.000008>
    1662064377.603615 stat("/path/to/slurm/current/lib64/tls/x86_64", 0x7fffffffc3f0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory) <0.000008>
    1662064377.603638 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/path/to/slurm/current/lib64/tls/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory) <0.000009>
    1662064377.603661 stat("/path/to/slurm/current/lib64/tls", 0x7fffffffc3f0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory) <0.000008>
    1662064377.603684 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/path/to/slurm/current/lib64/haswell/avx512_1/x86_64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory) <0.000008>
    1662064377.603707 stat("/path/to/slurm/current/lib64/haswell/avx512_1/x86_64", 0x7fffffffc3f0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory) <0.000008>
    1662064377.603730 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/path/to/slurm/current/lib64/haswell/avx512_1/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory) <0.000008>
    1662064377.603753 stat("/path/to/slurm/current/lib64/haswell/avx512_1", 0x7fffffffc3f0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory) <0.000008>
    1662064377.603775 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/path/to/slurm/current/lib64/haswell/x86_64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory) <0.000008>
    1662064377.603798 stat("/path/to/slurm/current/lib64/haswell/x86_64", 0x7fffffffc3f0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory) <0.000008>
    1662064377.603820 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/path/to/slurm/current/lib64/haswell/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory) <0.000009>
    1662064377.603844 stat("/path/to/slurm/current/lib64/haswell", 0x7fffffffc3f0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory) <0.000009>
    1662064377.603867 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/path/to/slurm/current/lib64/avx512_1/x86_64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory) <0.000008>
    1662064377.603890 stat("/path/to/slurm/current/lib64/avx512_1/x86_64", 0x7fffffffc3f0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory) <0.000008>
    1662064377.603913 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/path/to/slurm/current/lib64/avx512_1/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory) <0.000008>
    1662064377.603935 stat("/path/to/slurm/current/lib64/avx512_1", 0x7fffffffc3f0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory) <0.000008>
    1662064377.603958 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/path/to/slurm/current/lib64/x86_64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory) <0.000009>
    1662064377.603981 stat("/path/to/slurm/current/lib64/x86_64", 0x7fffffffc3f0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory) <0.000008>
    1662064377.604004 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/path/to/slurm/current/lib64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory) <0.000009>
    1662064377.604028 stat("/path/to/slurm/current/lib64", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0 <0.000010>
    1662064377.604053 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3 <0.000007>
    1662064377.604074 fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=93583, ...}) = 0 <0.000006>
    1662064377.604095 mmap(NULL, 93583, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x155555537000 <0.000007>
    1662064377.604117 close(3)              = 0 <0.000006>
    1662064377.604139 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3 <0.000007>
    1662064377.604160 read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\2607\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832 <0.000006>
    1662064377.604183 fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=3149120, ...}) = 0 <0.000006>
    1662064377.604203 mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x155555535000 <0.000006>
    1662064377.604225 mmap(NULL, 3938144, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x155554f69000 <0.000007>
    1662064377.604245 mprotect(0x155555122000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0 <0.000010>
    1662064377.604268 mmap(0x155555321000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1b8000) = 0x155555321000 <0.000009>
    1662064377.604294 mmap(0x155555327000, 14176, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x155555327000 <0.000007>
    1662064377.604318 close(3)              = 0 <0.000006>
    1662064377.604345 arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x155555536580) = 0 <0.000006>
    1662064377.604394 mprotect(0x155555321000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0 <0.000008>
    1662064377.604426 mprotect(0x555555769000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0 <0.000007>
    1662064377.604448 mprotect(0x155555553000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0 <0.000007>
    1662064377.604468 munmap(0x155555537000, 93583) = 0 <0.000011>
    1662064377.604539 brk(NULL)             = 0x55555576b000 <0.000006>
    1662064377.604559 brk(0x55555578c000)   = 0x55555578c000 <0.000007>
    1662064377.604579 brk(NULL)             = 0x55555578c000 <0.000006>
    1662064377.604601 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory) <0.000007>
    1662064377.604631 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/locale.alias", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3 <0.000006>
    1662064377.604652 fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2997, ...}) = 0 <0.000006>
    1662064377.604673 read(3, "# Locale name alias data base.\n#"..., 4096) = 2997 <0.000006>
    1662064377.604703 read(3, "", 4096)     = 0 <0.000006>
    1662064377.604722 close(3)              = 0 <0.000006>
    1662064377.604750 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_IDENTIFICATION", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory) <0.000007>
    1662064377.604772 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/en_US.utf8/LC_IDENTIFICATION", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3 <0.000007>
    1662064377.604793 fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=368, ...}) = 0 <0.000005>
    1662064377.604812 mmap(NULL, 368, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x15555554d000 <0.000007>
    1662064377.604832 close(3)              = 0 <0.000005>
    1662064377.604852 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib64/gconv/gconv-modules.cache", O_RDONLY) = 3 <0.000006>
    1662064377.604872 fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=26998, ...}) = 0 <0.000005>
    1662064377.604892 mmap(NULL, 26998, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, 3, 0) = 0x155555546000 <0.000007>
    1662064377.604911 close(3)              = 0 <0.000005>
    1662064377.604935 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_MEASUREMENT", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory) <0.000006>
    1662064377.604956 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/en_US.utf8/LC_MEASUREMENT", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3 <0.000006>
    1662064377.604976 fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=23, ...}) = 0 <0.000006>
    1662064377.604996 mmap(NULL, 23, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x155555545000 <0.000007>
    1662064377.605017 close(3)              = 0 <0.000005>
    1662064377.605040 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_TELEPHONE", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory) <0.000006>
    1662064377.605060 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/en_US.utf8/LC_TELEPHONE", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3 <0.000006>
    1662064377.605081 fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=59, ...}) = 0 <0.000006>
    1662064377.605101 mmap(NULL, 59, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x155555544000 <0.000006>
    1662064377.605121 close(3)              = 0 <0.000006>
    1662064377.605143 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_ADDRESS", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory) <0.000006>
    1662064377.605164 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/en_US.utf8/LC_ADDRESS", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3 <0.000006>
    1662064377.605184 fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=167, ...}) = 0 <0.000006>
    1662064377.605203 mmap(NULL, 167, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x155555543000 <0.000006>
    1662064377.605223 close(3)              = 0 <0.000005>
    1662064377.605245 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_NAME", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory) <0.000006>
    1662064377.605266 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/en_US.utf8/LC_NAME", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3 <0.000006>
    1662064377.605286 fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=77, ...}) = 0 <0.000005>
    1662064377.605305 mmap(NULL, 77, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x155555542000 <0.000006>
    1662064377.605324 close(3)              = 0 <0.000005>
    1662064377.605347 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_PAPER", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory) <0.000006>
    1662064377.605367 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/en_US.utf8/LC_PAPER", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3 <0.000006>
    1662064377.605388 fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=34, ...}) = 0 <0.000006>
    1662064377.605407 mmap(NULL, 34, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x155555541000 <0.000006>
    1662064377.605426 close(3)              = 0 <0.000005>
    1662064377.605450 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory) <0.000006>
    1662064377.605471 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/en_US.utf8/LC_MESSAGES", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3 <0.000007>
    1662064377.605492 fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=29, ...}) = 0 <0.000008>
    1662064377.605514 close(3)              = 0 <0.000006>
    1662064377.605533 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/en_US.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/SYS_LC_MESSAGES", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3 <0.000006>
    1662064377.605554 fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=57, ...}) = 0 <0.000005>
    1662064377.605573 mmap(NULL, 57, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x155555540000 <0.000006>
    1662064377.605592 close(3)              = 0 <0.000005>
    1662064377.605614 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_MONETARY", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory) <0.000006>
    1662064377.605636 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/en_US.utf8/LC_MONETARY", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3 <0.000007>
    1662064377.605656 fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=286, ...}) = 0 <0.000005>
    1662064377.605675 mmap(NULL, 286, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x15555553f000 <0.000007>
    1662064377.605695 close(3)              = 0 <0.000006>
    1662064377.605717 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_COLLATE", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory) <0.000006>
    1662064377.605738 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/en_US.utf8/LC_COLLATE", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3 <0.000006>
    1662064377.605758 fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2586930, ...}) = 0 <0.000005>
    1662064377.605777 mmap(NULL, 2586930, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x155554cf1000 <0.000007>
    1662064377.605797 close(3)              = 0 <0.000005>
    1662064377.605825 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_TIME", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory) <0.000006>
    1662064377.605847 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/en_US.utf8/LC_TIME", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3 <0.000007>
    1662064377.605868 fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=3316, ...}) = 0 <0.000006>
    1662064377.605889 mmap(NULL, 3316, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x15555553e000 <0.000007>
    1662064377.605909 close(3)              = 0 <0.000006>
    1662064377.605931 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_NUMERIC", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory) <0.000006>
    1662064377.605952 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/en_US.utf8/LC_NUMERIC", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3 <0.000006>
    1662064377.605972 fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=54, ...}) = 0 <0.000005>
    1662064377.605991 mmap(NULL, 54, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x15555553d000 <0.000006>
    1662064377.606011 close(3)              = 0 <0.000005>
    1662064377.606035 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_CTYPE", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory) <0.000006>
    1662064377.606056 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/en_US.utf8/LC_CTYPE", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3 <0.000006>
    1662064377.606076 fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=337024, ...}) = 0 <0.000005>
    1662064377.606095 mmap(NULL, 337024, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x1555554e2000 <0.000006>
    1662064377.606115 close(3)              = 0 <0.000005>
    1662064377.606142 openat(AT_FDCWD, "newfilethat", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK, 0666) = 3 <33.971332>
    1662064411.577554 dup2(3, 0)            = 0 <0.000018>
    1662064411.577613 close(3)              = 0 <0.000015>
    1662064411.577662 utimensat(0, NULL, NULL, 0) = 0 <0.017514>
    1662064411.595221 close(0)              = 0 <0.000216>
    1662064411.595453 close(1)              = 0 <0.000006>
    1662064411.595474 close(2)              = 0 <0.000006>
    1662064411.595512 exit_group(0)         = ?
    1662064411.595645 +++ exited with 0 +++
    % time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
    ------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
     99.94   33.971842      539235        63        45 openat
      0.05    0.017515       17514         1           utimensat
      0.00    0.000348          16        21           close
      0.00    0.000280           8        32        30 stat
      0.00    0.000204         203         1           execve
      0.00    0.000129           7        18           mmap
      0.00    0.000106           6        17           fstat
      0.00    0.000034           8         4           mprotect
      0.00    0.000028           6         4           brk
      0.00    0.000020           6         3           read
      0.00    0.000018          18         1           dup2
      0.00    0.000012           6         2         1 arch_prctl
      0.00    0.000011          11         1           munmap
      0.00    0.000008           7         1         1 access
    ------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
    100.00   33.990554                   169        77 total
```

Comment: do you have a super long `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`? that could slow down library loads

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but no `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/cm/shared/apps/slurm/current/lib64/slurm:/cm/shared/apps/slurm/current/lib64`

Comment: also check your `ld.so.conf` or `ld.so.conf.d`

Comment: Not much there either:
` /etc/ld.so.conf

/etc/ld.so.conf.d
/etc/ld.so.conf.d/atlas-x86_64.conf
/etc/ld.so.conf.d/bind-export-x86_64.conf
/etc/ld.so.conf.d/kernel-4.18.0-193.el8.x86_64.conf
/etc/ld.so.conf.d/srvadmin-deng.conf
/etc/ld.so.conf.d/srvadmin-hapi-x86_64.conf
/etc/ld.so.conf.d/srvadmin-idrac7.conf
/etc/ld.so.conf.d/srvadmin-isvc.conf
 /etc/ld.so.conf.d/srvadmin-omacore.conf
 /etc/ld.so.conf.d/srvadmin-omcommon.conf
/etc/ld.so.conf.d/srvadmin-storelib.conf`

Comment: well those are the configuration files but they can contain many paths. use `grep -h '^[[:space:]]*/' /etc/ld.so.conf /etc/ld.so.conf.d/*` to list all search paths

Comment: `grep -h '^[[:space:]]*/' /etc/ld.so.conf /etc/ld.so.conf.d/*
/usr/lib64/atlas
/usr/lib64//bind9-export/
/opt/dell/srvadmin/lib64
/opt/dell/srvadmin/lib64/openmanage
/opt/dell/srvadmin/lib64
/opt/dell/srvadmin/lib64
/opt/dell/srvadmin/lib64/srvadmin-idrac7
/opt/dell/srvadmin/lib64
/opt/dell/srvadmin/lib64/srvadmin-isvc
/opt/dell/srvadmin/lib64
/opt/dell/srvadmin/lib64/openmanage
/opt/dell/srvadmin/lib64
/opt/dell/srvadmin/lib64/openmanage
/opt/dell/srvadmin/lib64`